# Group generated by some transpositions in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $T \subset S_n$ be a set of transpositions. Let $G = \langle T \rangle$. I want to show that $G$ has at least $n - |T|$ orbits.

Am I correct in assuming that "orbits" here is synonymous with "conjugacy classes"?

How do I go about getting started on this? I can't seem to get a foothold.

Comment: Do you how orbits are [defined](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Orbit_(Group_Theory))?

Comment: Orbits are not conjugacy classes here. They are orbits of the action on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Conjugacy class means orbits for some particular action, not the one considered here.

Comment: @mrtaurho Yes, I do. Orbits are a partition of a set according to the equivalence classes of some action of a group on that set. Since conjugation is usually the action in question and a specific action wasn't mentioned here, I assumed the action here is conjugation.

Comment: @YCor Since conjugation is usually the action in question and a specific action wasn't mentioned here, I assumed the action here is conjugation.

Comment: Try to check definitions rather what you think is "usually" true to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 1):

We prove this by induction. For one transposition $(ij) $, the orbits are $\{i, j\} $ and $\{k\} $ for $k\notin \{i, j\} $. Otherwise, suppose there are $m$ transpositions generating the subgroup. If we restrict to the first $m-1$, we have distinct orbits $O_p$ for $1\leq p\leq M$ with $M\geq n-m+1$.

Let the last transposition be $(ij) $. If there is a single orbit $O_p$ containing both $i$ and $j$, then the orbits of the larger subgroup are the same and the result follows. Otherwise, there is an orbit $O_p$ containing $i$ and a distinct orbit $O_q$ containing $j$. Adding $(ij) $ joins these two orbits and has no effect on the others, so there are $M-1$ orbits, and the result follows by induction.

Comment: How do you know, in the case that $i$ and $j$ are in distinct orbits, that adding $(ij)$ to the list of transpositions doesn't somehow screw with the other orbits? Adding another transposition to the generating set may well allow some other permutation to be realized.

Comment: @Jungle Anything that you couldn't move to an $i$ or a $j$ before still can't be moved to an $i$ or a $j$. I can make it more precise later if necessary.